# Inconsistency in python help('string') versus help(list)?

Tags: python

When I type `help('string')` in the python interpreter I get information about the string class. There,`upper()` is indicated as a function. Yet I can only call it as a method like     `"hi".upper()` instead of `upper("hi")`.
So one could assume that any method will be indicated as a function in the docstrings of the built in modules. Yet when I do `help('list')` , methods of the list class are indicated as methods in the docstrings!!
Why is this so? Only because the person who wrote the doctrings was inconsistent or that different people wrote it? Or do these methods(the ones called 'functions' versus the ones called 'methods' in the docstrings) actually have different properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you searched for `help('string')`, you were looking for the docstrings of the **`string` module**. If you do `help(str)` or `help('str')` you'll get the docstrings of the `str` type, and here `upper` appears as a method!

As you can see here, the function `upper` from the `string` module is actually a function and not a method:

```
>>> upper('hi')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'upper' is not defined
>>> 'hi'.upper() # method from the str type
'HI'
>>> from string import upper
>>> upper('hi') # function from the string module
'HI'
```

Comment: Thnx. Ok, so str is the name of a class defined in the module ____builtin____ while string is the name of a module.                   Why did they make another string module when there is already a class defined inside the ____builtin____ module?

Comment: @Bentley4 The `string` module has a lot of useful stuff for string processing that wouldn't make much sense inside the `str` class. Stuff like: constants (digits, uppercase characters), templates, formatters ... More info [here](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html)

Answer (score 2):

You mean to do `help('str')`, not `help('string')`. `str` is a type, `string` is  a module providing functions for working with strings.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an instance of that object and then calling help on that instance.

So these all work:

```
help(1)
help({})
help([])
help('')
help(dir)
help(help)
```

Help grabs the docstring for that instance, and gives it back to you.
When you create your own objects, you can put in useful docstrings or whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with what you see.

```
>>> help('string')
```

Will show you the `string` module documentation. And it looks like there's an `upper` function inside:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.upper('hello')
'hello'
```

I'd say that this `upper` is the same that is called if you do:

```
>>> 'hello'.upper()
```

But I'm not sure.

Notice that a string `''` is a `str` type not a `string` type. This means that you're probably looking for:

```
>>> help('str')
```

And here you'll see too the `str.upper` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `'string'` is a `string`. So is `'list'`

To get a similar result for `lists`, try `help([])`

Comment: No... it is perfectly valid to do `help('list')` to get help on a list

Comment: Wow... I did not know that. `x = 'list'` and then `help(x)`. That is some unexpected behavior!

Comment: @veiset: It looks like strings are the one kind of object you can't get help on by calling it on an instance