# Why does help(42) work but neither help("") nor help("x")?

Tags: python, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inconsistency in python help(‘string’) versus help(list)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998488/inconsistency-in-python-helpstring-versus-helplist)

In the interactive shell of Python, if I type `help(42)` I get all the information about int objects. If I type `help("")` I get nothing and if I type `help("x")` I get "no Python documentation found for 'x'".

I know I can type `help(str)`, but I'd like to understand why are the other two working differently from `help(42)`?

Comment: just a guess: according to wikipedia, the number 42 has received considerable attention in popular culture as a result of its central appearance in The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy as the "Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything".

Comment: when all fails, read the doc: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [the documentation on the help function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#help):

> If no argument is given, the interactive help system starts on the interpreter console. If the argument is a string, then the string is looked up as the name of a module, function, class, method, keyword, or documentation topic, and a help page is printed on the console. If the argument is any other kind of object, a help page on the object is generated.

In other words, when `help` is given a class or type, it returns help on that class or type.

```
class C: pass
help(C)
```

When `help` is given any instance other than a string, like `help(1)`, it provides documentation on the type of that variable (`int`, `float`, or a defined class).

```
help(1)
help(C())
```

When it is given a string, it provides documentation on the type or class that that string refers to. If you want help with the `str` class itself, you can do:

```
help(str)
```

or

```
help("str")
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#help):

> *help([object])*
>
> Invoke the built-in help system. (This function is intended for
>   interactive use.) If no argument is given, the interactive help system
>   starts on the interpreter console. If the argument is a string, then
>   the string is looked up as the name of a module, function, class,
>   method, keyword, or documentation topic, and a help page is printed on
>   the console. If the argument is any other kind of object, a help page
>   on the object is generated.

So the behaviour is different only if the argument of `help()` is a string.